# read file into an array excluding the the commented out lines

Tags: ruby, file-io, puppet

I'm almost a Ruby-nOOb (have just the knowledge of Ruby to write some basic .erb template or Puppet custom-facts). Looks like my requirements fairly simple but can't get my head around it.

Trying to write a `.erb` template, where it reads a file (with space delimited lines) to an array and then handle each array element according to the requirements. This is what I got so far:

```
fname = "webURI.txt"

def myArray()
    #if defined? $fname
    if File.exist?($fname) and File.file?($fname)
        IO.readlines($fname)
    end
end

myArray.each_index do |i|
    myLine = myArray[i].split(' ')
    puts myLine[0] +"\t=> "+ myLine.last
end
```

Which works just fine, except (for obvious reason) for the line that is commented out or blank lines. I also want to make sure that when spitted (by space) up, the line shouldn't have more than two fields in it; a file like this:

```
# This is a COMMENT
#
# Puppet dashboard
puppet controller-all-local.example.co.uk:80

# Nagios monitoring
nagios controller-all-local.example.co.uk::80/nagios
tac talend-tac-local.example.co.uk:8080/org.talend.admin

mng console talend-mca-local.example.co.uk:8080/amc     # Line with three fields
```

So, basically these two things I'd like to achieve:

1. Read the lines into array, stripping off everything after the first `#`
2. Split each element and print a message if the number id more than two

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!!

---

***Update*** 25/02

Thanks guy for your help!!

The `blank`thing doesn't work for at all; throwing in this error; but I kinda failed to understand why:

> *undefined method `blank?' for "\n":String (NoMethodError)*

The array: `myArray`, which I get is actually something like this (using `p` instead of `puts`:

```
["\n", "puppet controller-all-local.example.co.uk:80\n", "\n", "\n", "nagios controller-all-local.example.co.uk::80/nagios\n", .....     \n"]
```

Hence, I had to do this to get around this prob:

```
$fname = "webURI.txt"

def myArray()
    if File.exist?($fname) and File.file?($fname)
        IO.readlines($fname).map { |arr| arr.gsub(/#.*/,'') }
    end
end

# remove blank lines
SSS = myArray.reject { |ln| ln.start_with?("\n") }

SSS.each_index do |i|
    myLine = SSS[i].split(' ')

    if myLine.length > 2
        puts "Too many arguments!!!"

    elsif myLine.length == 1
        puts "page"+ i.to_s + "\t=> " + myLine[0]

    else
        puts myLine[0] +"\t=> "+ myLine.last
    end
end
```

You are most welcome to improve the code. cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

```
goodArray = myArray.reject do |line|
  line.start_with?('#') || line.split(' ').length > 2
end
```

This would reject whatever that either starts with # or the split returns an array of more than two elements returning you an array of only good items.

**Edit:**

For your inline commenting you can then do

```
goodArray.map do |line|
  line.gsub(/#.*/, '')
end
```

Comment: You might want to add a `.reject(&blank?)` to remove blank lines too.

Comment: Thanks Guy! Also, how can I strip-off every thing from the first `#` to handle the in-line comment `(e.g. Abc Bcd  # in-line comment)`? cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers, I'd do it in the first block `myArray.reject do |line| line.blank? || line.start_with?('#') || line.split(' ').length > 2 end`